# fixed positioned banner - responsive issue on smaller devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a website it has banner responsiveness issue on smaller devices. Also logo pulls towards right as well.

Website [link](http://designproshop.com/Site/index.html).

```
#rev_slider_1_1949_wrapper
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    max-width: 1200px !important
}
```

[image]

please do help me fix this bug. thanks in advance

Comment: Please define "banner responsiveness issue"!

Comment: as you can see in screen shot on resizing window banner is not resizing its going all the way to right as red arrow showing on the right, while leaving white space on the left... please let me know if I am still not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your `.container_24` element a `width: 100%` in the respective stylesheet (720.css).

Comment: I'm glad it fixed your issue. But I can't reproduce your logo error. For me it always stays centered while resizing..